# How to enable created local windows user to log into his account from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, user-accounts

I've created local windows account and added it to group Users using classes from System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace. Then I tried to log into that newly created account (manually not from C#) and got error 'user profile service failed user profile cannot be loaded'. My C# code is:

```
      try
        {
            // Create context for server and create new user if one not exists
            string userID = GetUserID(userName, userType);
            PrincipalContext serverContext = GetDefaultPrincipalContext();
            if (DoesExist(userID, serverContext))
            {
                throw new Exception("User already exists!");
            }
            UserPrincipal newUser = new UserPrincipal(serverContext, userID, userID, true);

            // Get description of user from its privilege and save user if everything went OK
            var description = GetDescriptionFromUserType(userType);
            if (null != description)
            {
                newUser.Description = description;
                newUser.Save(); 

                // Add user to group so it is displayed in Control Panel
                GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(serverContext, USERS_GROUP);
                group.Members.Add(newUser);
                group.Save();
                group.Dispose();
                newUser.Dispose();
                serverContext.Dispose();
                success = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.LogError(TYPE, e.Message);
            DeleteUser(userName, userType);
        }
```

What i'm missing?

I've forgot to write, GetDefaultPrincipalContext() returns new PrincipalContext(Context.Machine, null)...

**UPDATE:**
Just to mention that I haven't made home directory and all the stuff inside it for new user on path C:\Users\NewUser... And what is strange (in my opinion), one isn't made automatically.

Comment: That's a very odd error message.  Is your system configured to require the use of roaming profiles?  (This is a group policy setting.)

Comment: I'm not sure, it has default settings for Windows 8.1 so I'm thinking not.

Comment: Is the machine joined to a domain?

Comment: I assume the userID string doesn't contain any odd characters?

Comment: Looking at the specs for UserPrincipal, you might need to set some of the other properties besides the description.  In particular, try setting `newUser.Name=UserID`.

Comment: First let me thank you for your help. :) It doesn't contain any odd characters (SandraESTUDENT is value of userID in unit test). Can it have something to do with Windows 8.1? I'm asking you that cause to log in into Windows 8.1 you need to make Windows account with e-mail and stuff... Maybe isn't possible to create local user account this way...

Comment: It certainly should be possible to create an account this way.  All the cloud stuff in Windows 8 account management is still optional.  MS is usually pretty hot on backwards compatibility so it seems unlikely that programmatically creating a local account would require any extra steps in Windows 8.  I have Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 boxes available, if I get a chance tomorrow I'll experiment a little.  In the meantime, try setting `newUser.Name` and, if that doesn't work, the other settable properties.

Comment: I'll try and if anything works I'll post a comment or solution here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing an answer in case that anyone sees this post and thinks that the code above is no good. Actually code is working nicely on every other windows machine on which I tried to run it. I don't know what is the issue on my personal computer but the problem is definitely not in code... I will ask other question to resolve my windows problem...

Comment: What does the DeleteUser method do?